# Ecpiselink NativeQuery from other schema

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

i would execute a simple select with eclipselink from another schema like this:

```
     Query query = em.createNativeQuery("select * from another_schema.TABLE_NAME");
     List returnList = query.getResultList();
```

But when i run my application i get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: The transaction is no longer active - status: 'Marked rollback.
Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: The transaction is no longer active - status: 'Marked rollback. [Reason=weblogic.transaction.internal.TimedOutException: Transaction timed out after 30 seconds 
BEA1-0091256F3B0B87325B62]'. No further JDBC access is allowed within this transaction.
```

I have privileges to run this sql command, i tried with sql developer, and it's working.

Can anybody please help me, how should I run this NativeQuery?

Thank you!

Comment: Are other queries working?  How many results are returned and how long does the query take?  Is this schema visible from the user the application is using?

Comment: Yes the schema is visible. The query works in toad or in sql developer. 300000 rows return and it takes about 10 second..

Comment: How long between when you start a transaction and when you execute the query?  Try upping your transaction timeouts so the query and the process can complete

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error "No further JDBC access is allowed within this transaction." by setting the transaction in Weblogic as "Local Transaction".
Just uncheck the transaction option: Supports Global Transactions